# Windows 10 Recovery keeps showing on boot after fresh install of Zorin OS Lite

Tags: linux, windows, boot, efi, zorin

I've recently stumped on a problem after installing Zorin OS Lite 64bit on my old laptop which was running Windows 10 64bit. So basically after installing Zorin OS I was not able to boot into my OS normally hence showing me the Recovery on boot with the following error code: 0xc0000034

It gives me the option to press ESC to go into UEFI Firmware Settings and whence I press F9 I get to go to Boot Options to choose manually Zorin OS efi file. So my question is how do I manage to have my Zorin OS loaded on boot automatically?

Comment: What model is your laptop? Is it BIOS or EFI?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can boot into Linux, do boot repair:

- Connect to the Internet
- In Terminal enter the following commands:

  ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
  ```
- Click the "Recommended repair" button.

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't help unfortunately. It still shows Windows 10 Recovery blue screen on boot. It gets annoying becouse everytime i turn up my laptop I must go and custom select my boot efi file for Zorin OS. Anyway thank you for your help.